# Command works as "\csname cmd \endcsname" but not as "\cmd"

Tags: macros, programming, csname

I'm trying to create a command (`\dummy`) for dynamic macro definition. It is supposed to return a macro that is named dynamically (`#3`) with the content of `#2` concatenated after `#1` iterations.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{xifthen}


\newcounter{loopcnt}


\makeatletter

\newcommand{\dummy}[3]{%
    \edef\temp{#1}
    %
    \forloop[-1]{loopcnt}{#1}{\value{loopcnt} > 0}{%
        \ifthenelse{\theloopcnt = \temp}{%
            \edef\tempcmd{M}
        }{%
            \edef\tempcmd{M;\tempcmd}
        }
    }
    \expandafter\def\csname #3 \endcsname{\tempcmd}
}

\makeatother


\begin{document}


\dummy{5}{M}{varSpec}

\csname varSpec \endcsname % This works - outputs "M;M;M;M;M"

\varSpec % This doesn't work


\end{document}
```

I am curious why calling `\csname varSpec \endcsname` afterwards works as expected but calling `\varSpec` doesn't? How can I get `\varSpec` work?

Comment: you are defining a command name with a space at the end. Use `#3\endcsname`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Such a simple mistake!

Comment: apart from the space token after `#3` you have lots of other space tokens you probably want to remove by using `%` at ends of lines each use of `\dummy` adds 5 space tokens to the output plus an extra one for each iteration of the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a simpler way to do the job:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\dummy}{mO{;}mm}
 {
  \cs_new:cpx { #4 }
   {
    \exp_not:n { #3 }
    \prg_replicate:nn { #1 - 1 } { \exp_not:n { #2 #3 } }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\dummy{5}{M}{varSpec}
\dummy{3}[\textit{\&}]{\textbf{a}}{varBf}

\varSpec % This doesn't work

\varBf

\end{document}
```

With `\cs_new:cpx` the command with the name specified in the trailing argument is built, doing full expansion of `\prg_replicate:nn`. However, the main argument and the separator are protected from expansion, in case they contain “risky” commands such as `\textbf` as in the example.

Note that with this approach you can even say

```
\dummy{\value{mycounter}}{x}{myCmd}
```

Another advantage, besides simplicity, is that endlines are ignored between `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff`

You could do it also with your code, of course:

```latex
\newcommand{\dummy}[3]{%
    \forloop[-1]{loopcnt}{#1}{\value{loopcnt} > 0}{%
        \ifthenelse{\value{loopcnt} = #1}{%
            \edef\tempcmd{#2}%
        }{%
            \edef\tempcmd{#2;\tempcmd}%
        }%
    }%
    \expandafter\let\csname #3\endcsname\tempcmd
}
```

Note the last line: with your code you would have defined `\varSpec` to expand to `\tempcmd`, which would change if another call of `\dummy` intervenes. With `\let` this does not happen.

Also, no space should go between `#3` and `\endcsname`, or it would become part of the macro's name.